# react-native - App or Configuration Specific Code

Tags: react-native

React-native allow to have a platform-specific code, like .native. .ios.   (https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code)...

I'm looking for a way to create custom-specific extensions which would allow loading specific code depending on a custom configuration. Which would be useful, for example to have :

- Customdata.release.ts
- Customdata.preprod.ts
- Customdata.dev.ts

The most important part is to avoid having Customdata.dev.ts embed in the release bundle. Maybe babel would be able to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would have to use .env to separate each environment. In it you could add if it will run in production or in dev.

I use it that way in projects that I work with RN, it works very well. I have never seen in any project separate this way by release and prod environment.

I believe it is possible, using the React Native global variable "**DEV**", however, if you were to approve this on a physical device, it would not work, because the global variable separates the emulator from the physical.

So in that case I think the best way would be to use .env, you would have a lot more control over things.

Comment: .env would only allow to have some custom configuration variables, not entire different behavior with a specific file.

DEV, is working, but allow only two configuration (true | false) and it wouldn't allow separate files. More other it's not configurable (to make beta release for example).

Answer (score 0):

Confused exactly what you want. You can allow more than 2 configurations using a global configuration file. Something like this:

```
// config.ts
export interface DynamicConfig {
  apiUrl: string;
  environment: "DEV" | "TST" | "AKC" | "PROD";
}

export const defaultConfig: DynamicConfig = {
  apiUrl: "http://localhost:8080/undefinedApiUrl",
  environment: "DEV"
};

class GlobalConfig {
  config: DynamicConfig = defaultConfig;
}

export const globalConfig = new GlobalConfig();

export const globalConfigUrl = "config.json";
```

Then load the configuration before loading React in index file:

```
// index.tsx:
import axios from "axios";
import React, {ReactElement} from "react";
import App from "./App";
import {globalConfig, globalConfigUrl} from "./configuration/config";

axios.get(globalConfigUrl)
  .then((response) => {
    globalConfig.config = response.data;
    return <App />;
  })
  .catch(e => {
      return <p style={{color: "red", textAlign: "center"}}>Error while fetching global config</p>;
  })
  .then((reactElement: ReactElement) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      reactElement,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
  });
```

And you can then use the configuration like so:

```
// BusinessService.ts
import { globalConfig } from "../configuration/config";

export class BusinessService {
  public static getSomeDataFromApi(): void {
    console.log("service method performing an action with the following config: ", globalConfig.config);
  }
}
```

Comment: Source here: https://profinit.eu/en/blog/build-once-deploy-many-in-react-dynamic-configuration-properties/